# Retrieve a last inserted user_id in zend db

Tags: php, zend-db

How to retrieve last inserted user id? I have to use that user id for inserting that user id into next query that also should be done in this transaction only.
my query:

```
$db->beginTransaction ();
$sql = $db->query ( "INSERT INTO user( user_id, title)
 VALUES ( :p_user_id, :p_title )",
 array ( 'p_user_id' => '', 'p_title' => $title ) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this method to retrive the last insert id :

```
$db->lastInsertId()
```

With you code :

```
$db->beginTransaction ();
$sql = $db->query ( "INSERT INTO user( user_id, title) VALUES ( :p_user_id, :p_title )",
array ( 'p_user_id' => '', 'p_title' => $title ) );
$db->lastInsertId() ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use insert() method for inserting data. Also it returns ID.

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Table('user');
$lastInsertId = $db->insert(array('user_id' => '', 'title' => $title));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this this should work:

```
$groupID = Engine_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->lastInsertId();
```